# openbgpd: announcing our prefix

Tags: networking, unix, bgp

i use quagga as active for bgp4 but i am searching openbgpd. 
I installed openbgpd on freebsd. i am new at openbgpd.

I have an AS and also my customer's AS. I have 2 IPSs for internet.
how can i restrict sending all our prefixes towards my isps by AS or me and my ip prefixes ?
Namely i want to apply filter not in order to send prefixes the isp from other isp. 
Could you give me an example ?

is there any mailing lists or forum about openbgpd ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

> how can i restrict sending all our prefixes towards my isps by AS or me and my ip prefixes? Namely i want to apply filter not in order to send prefixes the isp from other isp. Could you give me an example?

In your `bgpd.conf` you use the `announce self` configuration syntax (assuming you want to announce 192.168.1.0/24 from AS 100 to your neighbors at 192.0.2.1 (AS 777) and 192.0.2.9 (AS 778))...

```
# FILE: bgpd.conf
AS 100
network    192.168.1.0/24  
router-id  192.0.2.2

neighbor 192.0.2.1 {
    remote-as           777
    descr               upstream
    local-address       192.0.2.2
    announce            self
}
neighbor 192.0.2.9 {
    remote-as           778
    descr               upstream
    local-address       192.0.2.10
    announce            self
}
```

Also look up [Henning Brauer's openbgp config notes](http://quigon.bsws.de/papers/euroBSDCon2004/mgp00033.html)

[AS112 also has some good information](http://public.as112.net/node/23)

BTW, [openbgpd](http://www.openbgpd.org/) is also available for [pfSense](http://www.pfsense.org/), as it's a BSD-based platform

Comment: Ok 
I have also a customer who has an AS. I have to send its prefixes towards our 2 isps ( as777 and as778 ).

How can i add that above conf ?

Comment: You will need to `announce all` to the upstreams and [use filter language](http://quigon.bsws.de/papers/euroBSDCon2004/mgp00038.html)

Comment: If you're going to run a complex network like this, there's no substitute for you actually learning BGP and the configuration language for the tool you've chosen to run it.

Comment: i am looking for the equivalents for openbgpd of some expressions in the quagga/zebra. because i want to migrate openbgpd instead of quagga. But i am novice at openbgpd. thanks

Comment: "announce all" and my customer AS200 and its prefix 192.168.200.0/24 and my prefix 192.168.1.0/24   by that of,                                 announce all                                                     deny from any
allow from any inet prefix 192.168.200.0/24 prefixlen >= 24     allow from any inet prefix 192.168.10.0/24 prefixlen >= 24                 does it be enough ?

Comment: Thank you Mike I wonder about is there an equivalent of allowas-in in cisco/quagga for openbgpd ?
Or do i have to count on my isps' solutions such as interrouting? Meanwhile i read the documents.
is there a book or webpage about openbgpd ?
thanks
best wishes

Comment: is there a bgp forum site related to openbgpd ?